# What is another word for street-wise?

Tags: synonyms

Apart from 'street-smart' what is another word for street-wise?

Comment: How do you plan to use the term?  Could you provide an example sentence, and explain why *street-wise* isn't suitable?

Answer (score 2):

How about (the surprisingly old) ***worldly-wise*** -  Having or characterised by worldly wisdom; experienced in the ways of the world. (OED).  Or you could use ***savvy*** - Common sense, practical intelligence, shrewdness (OED).

c1400  (▸?a1387)    Langland Piers Plowman (Huntington HM 137) (1873) C. xi. l. 90   Ȝe worldliche wyse, vnwyse þat ȝe suffre, Lene hem and loue hem.
c1450  (▸1415)    Crowned King l. 85 in W. W. Skeat Langland's Piers Plowman (1873) 527   Þou most be worldly wys & ware þe be-tymes.

1562   Bp. J. Pilkington Expos. Abdyas Ee ij,   These Edomites..picked oute..the worldly wisest men, thei coulde finde to be their rulers.

1667   Milton Paradise Lost xii. 568   By things deemd weak Subverting worldly strong, and worldly wise By simply meek.

1792   M. Wollstonecraft Vindic. Rights Woman viii. 307,   I do not say that a prudent, worldly-wise man..may not sometimes obtain a more smooth reputation than a wiser or a better man.

1866   C. Kingsley Hereward the Wake I. iv. 148   The lads..imposed on by the cynical and worldly-wise tone which their..uncle had assumed.

1909   H. T. Peck Stud. in Several Literatures ix. 158   Unless you are a Londoner, unless you are worldly-wise, unless you have yourself a touch of cynicism in your nature, you will not greatly care for Thackeray.

1954   J. T. McNeill Hist. & Char. Calvinism ii. xiii. 206   True doctrine is a scandal to the worldly-wise.

2005   T. Aw Harmony Silk Factory iii. 295   ‘Ah bollocks,’ said Brother Rodney, a burly Australian who likes to think of himself as rather more worldly-wise than he is.

***1785   F. Grose Classical Dict. Vulgar Tongue   Scavey, sense, knowledge; ‘massa me no scavey’, master I don't know, (negroe language) perhaps from the French scavoir.***

1825   J. Jamieson Etymol. Dict. Sc. Lang. Suppl.   Savie, knowledge, experience, sagacity.

1890   ‘R. Boldrewood’ Colonial Reformer (1891) 47   He could ride the best, but the black boy had twice as much savey.

1964   E. B. White Let. 1 Feb. (1976) 515,   I felt deeply envious of their skills, their savvy, their self reliance, and their general deportment.

1978   J. Carroll Mortal Friends v. i. 496   Kennedy's reputation was for more savvy than that. He knew his history, didn't he, and its humbling lesson?

2007   J. Lott Warm Bucket Brigade p. xxii,   For all their savvy, the American founders never would have dreamt that the president would one day use the vice president as a human shield.

Comment: +1 for savvy... or even street-savvy

Comment: Of course the most up-to-the-minute words haven't made it into print yet (let alone the OED).

Answer (score 1):

A few decades ago I might have said this one was becoming somewhat "dated"...

> **fly**
>   1. (Chiefly British) *Mentally alert; sharp*

...but noting the second definition from [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fly) above,...

> 2. (Slang) *Fashionable; stylish*

...and this one from [onlineslangdictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/fly)...

> *Very good, excellent; "cool"; "awesome"*

...I think either it's made a spectacular comeback, or it never really went away.

Answer (score 1):

For another variation using *street*, consider *street-savvy*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with `sophisticated` or `worldly`.

Answer (score 0):

The word for this changes all the time, as choosing slang well is part of being street-wise to begin with.  So a lot of times this is a very 'period' word.  But some versions last.

A lot of words for this become general terms for productive intelligence like *savvy*.  But that leaves out the 'street', which is about observation, information and environment.  Or they come to mean *worldly*, but that indicates a breadth of exposure that *streetwise* does not imply.

The most generic form that works might be *with it*: in synch with the zeitgeist; most recently revived in the form *down with it* (which I think has now moved on, and become an indication of agreement and not awareness.)

My favorite of all time is *hep*.

And the most stable one may be *canny*, which is the information-rich version of *cunning*.