# A word for someone who lacks in academics but is still smart?

Tags: single-word-requests

What word other than 'street-smart' means you lack in academies but you are still smart?

Comment: Have you seen this question? The answers there so far might be helpful to you: [What is another word for street-wise?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289204/what-is-another-word-for-street-wise)

Answer (score 1):

Related to lack of academic studies ***[self-taught](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-taught)*** conveys the idea:

> - taught by oneself without the aid of formal instruction: *a self-taught typist.*

or  ***natural [talent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/talent):***

> - innate ability, aptitude, or faculty, esp when unspecified; above average ability: a talent for cooking; a child with talent.

- Street smart  does not specifically  imply (lack of) academic studies, but it just refers to the ability to deal with a difficult and possibly dangerous urban contexts.

> - ***[street smart](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/street+smart)*** - having the shrewd resourcefulness needed to survive in an urban environmentstreet smart - having the shrewd resourcefulness needed to survive in an urban environment

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about intelligence, rather than education, the word is 'smarts':

> 4. colloq. a. orig. and chiefly N. Amer.
>      (a) In *pl.* Intelligence, *esp. natural intelligence; cleverness, acumen, nous; wits*. Chiefly with *the*.

["smart, n.2". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/182447 (accessed November 24, 2015). Emphasis mine.]

As the entry notes, this sense of "natural intelligence" is strongly associated with the plural form of the noun, that is, 'smarts'. An example is

> You have the *smarts*.

---

With the proviso that you're asking about *education*, not *intelligence* (smarts), I fancy that

> **autodidactic**, *adj.*
>   ....
>   Of, relating to, or acquired by teaching oneself; self-taught.

["autodidactic, adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13414 (accessed November 24, 2015).]

would make the point.

The noun form of the word is

> **autodidact**, *n.* and *adj.*
>   A self-taught person.

(op. cit.)

Answer (score 0):

Natural ability.
Gumption.
Street-smart.
Inherent wisdom.
Innate intelligence.

Comment: Except "gumption", none of those fit the single-word criterion. Also, the OP explicitly mentioned she's looking for something *besides* "street-smart".

Answer (score 0):

I would use words like *gifted* and *talented* as they denote someone's natural ability.