# What's another word for street-smart?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What word would be another word that means street-smart?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The dictionary shows "[street-wise](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/street+smart)". But, please include full context where you want to use the word. I would recommend you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). ***Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered***.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://english.stackexchange.com/q/289204/103961

Answer (score 0):

'streetwise' I can say but there are also other words we can use like crafty, cunning or  canny.

street-smart exclusively deals with the problems of urban life. However, the words I have given above can be used in general.